# Encriptar url de <audio> para bloquear acceso al recurso mp3

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

tengo una lista de audios y dos tipos de usuarios. Unos pueden [reproducir] y otros [reproducir y descargar].

Los audios los cargo dinamicamente después de una consulta a la BD y los muestro con el siguiente código:

```
<audio controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="~/2018/05/11/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Cuando el usuario puede descargar el audio también, solo quito **controlsList="nodownload"**.

El usuario que solo puede reproducir los audios puede ver el código fuente de la página y obtener el link del audio **src="/2018/05/11/test.mp3**, abrirlo y descargarlo o con las herramientas de desarrollador quitar el **controlsList**.

Por todos los lados que lo veo esto está mal.

**He estado investigando y debería de encriptar mi url del audio para que el usuario no pueda acceder directamente al archivo**

**¿Alguien ha tenido una necesidad similar, algún consejo o recomendación?**

No se me ocurre como solucionar esto, mi única luz es el siguiente link : **https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/** pero no entiendo como implementar eso y si sea similar en audios.

Comment: En cuanto esté en el `audio`, cualquier usuario con conocimientos podrá ir a las herramientas del desarrollador de su navegador y localizar el fichero mp3. Lo más que vas a poder hacer es poner trabas para que no sea tan sencillo, pero los navegadores (y las extensiones/plugin) hoy en día ponen difícil hacer lo que intentas. EME suena interesante, pero parece que su soporte no está muy extendido.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora mismo lo que se me ocurre, si estás utilizando Apache como servidor web, podrías utilizar un fichero .htaccess para restringir el acceso a cualquier archivo con extensión .mp3

En el foro ingles tienes esta [contestación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127153/php-how-can-i-block-direct-url-access-to-a-file-but-still-allow-it-to-be-downl) para que te sirva de guía.